# Making a mulitdimensional jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I want to make a dynamic array of dynamic arrays, how can I do that?
I've tried with list of list where I use the `AddRange()` method.
I've also tried iterating through arrays.

Maybe it makes more sense to show what I'm trying to do.  I cannot get it to work:

```
String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
String[] linesArr;
String[][] MultiArr;
int i = 0;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("EFIX"))
    {
        linesArr = line.Split(delimiterChars);
        for (int x = 0; x < linesArr.Length; x++)
        {
            MultiArr[i][x] = linesArr[x];
        }
    Console.WriteLine(fixationsData[i]);
    i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with using a list of lists?

Comment: "What went wrong" in your attempt is really useful to people trying to help you.

Comment: Looks like you didn't assign anything to `MultiArr[i]`, so it's still `null`, so `MultiArr[i][x] = ...` is actually `null[x] = ...`. Oh and `MultiArr` itself is still `null`, unless you assigned it "of screen" somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ makes this pretty trivial.

```
string[][] data = File.ReadLines(filename)
    .Where(line => line.Contains("EFIX"))
    .Select(line => line.Split(delimiterChars))
    .ToArray();//omit this last call to allow the data to be streamed, 
    //greatly removing the memory footprint of the application at no real 
    //additional cost, assuming you have no compelling reason to eagerly 
    //load the whole file into memory.

foreach(var line in data)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: It seems to work except for outputting the line, as I get System.String[] but i need the strings inside. I added another foreach to accommodate this :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a list of list of strings should work fine. Here's what I'd write.

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
var multiArr = new List<List<string>>();
var i = 0;

foreach (var line in lines.Where(line => line.Contains("EFIX")))
{
    multiArr.Add(line.Split(delimiterChars).ToList());
    Console.WriteLine(fixationsData[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
String[] linesArr;
List<String[]> MultiArr = new List<String[]>();


foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("EFIX"))
    {
    linesArr = line.Split(delimiterChars);
    MultiArr.Add(linesArr);
    Console.WriteLine(fixationsData[i]);
    }
 }
```

This is a list of string arrays. This is what you are looking for.